# How to find correlated knowledge among different documents?

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval

Say I have a sequence of documents clicked by a user, how can I mine the identical or semanticly similar word/knowledge/phrases shared among different documents?

Maybe someone can give a paper or subject relating to my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be extracting the keywords from both documents and by using them as features you can compare the mutuality of the papers.

A better approach would be, build building knowledge graphs for the documents then comparing them. [This paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/148683663.pdf) illustrates a way of doing that.

[Another Source](https://medium.com/swlh/python-nlp-tutorial-information-extraction-and-knowledge-graphs-43a2a4c4556c)

[Another Source](https://medium.com/heuritech/knowledge-extraction-from-unstructured-texts-c279e3b8f92f)

However, if you want to build a deeper knowledge about the issue, for example how text-similarity, plagiarism or recommendation systems work, **A. Rajaraman and J. D. Ullman, Mining of Massive Datasets, Cambridge University Press, 2011** has very good content about the topic.

Comment: thank you very much, however, what I want to do is not **Knowledge Extraction**, rather I want to **Find both Same/Similar knowledges and words/phrases among documents.